# Eclipse Handler Parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse plugin which has the purpose of indexing and searching XML files for custom frameworks used by the application my team develops.

There is a toolbar with several buttons on it. Each button has its own command and each command is linked to a separate handler which brings up a search dialog.

The handlers differ only by which file type they search. Currently there are ten concrete handlers and one abstract. All of the functionality is handled in the abstract class, and the concrete classes only implement an abstract "get file type" method.

Ideally I would only have one handler. This means there would need to be a way to inject the enum into the base class directly.

I looked at command parameters, but this appears to be user-facing. I need something hard-coded where the command tells the handler "use this value." I don't care if this is a constructor argument or some hard-coded parameter in plugin.xml.

Thus far I have not been able to find a way to do this. Perhaps my Google-fu is weak, perhaps I am just not seeing it.

Is there a way to specify a hard-coded parameter to a handler constructor or to call a method to set a parameter after it is constructed but before it is invoked?

Comment: using a `Factory Pattern`?

Comment: Are you using the `org.eclipse.search.searchPages` extension point? (That could be an orthogonal decision. I'm just asking for more context.)

Comment: No, this is more along the lines of ctrl+shift+R to find a resource, except in this case, it is looking for specific types of XML elements in framework-specific XML files. But the idea of leveraging the search functionality even if only from a GUI perspective is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Command parameters are the right way to achieve that. What are the problems you face with that? [Here](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/12/commands-part-3-parameters-for-commands.html) is an example to use the parameters